# Directory.GetDirectories return empty string inside an async Task operation

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

I have a UWP application which perform to capture and process images from a camera.  This project leverage Microsoft Cognitive Services Face Recognition API and I'm exploring the application's existing functionality for awhile now.  My goal is that when the image of a person is identified by the camera (through Face Recognition API service), I want to show the associated image of that person.

With that, the images are captured and stored in a local directory of my machine.  I want to retrieve the image file and render it on the screen once the person is identified.

The code below shows the `async` Task method `ProcessCameraCapture`

```
private async Task ProcessCameraCapture(ImageAnalyzer e)
    {
        if (e == null)
        {
            this.UpdateUIForNoFacesDetected();
            this.isProcessingPhoto = false;
            return;
        }

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        await e.DetectFacesAsync();

        if (e.DetectedFaces.Any())
        {
            string names;
            await e.IdentifyFacesAsync();

            this.greetingTextBlock.Text = this.GetGreettingFromFaces(e, out names);

            if (e.IdentifiedPersons.Any())
            {
                this.greetingTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.GreenYellow);
                this.greetingSymbol.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.GreenYellow);
                this.greetingSymbol.Symbol = Symbol.Comment;

                GetSavedFilePhoto(names);
            }
            else
            {
                this.greetingTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Yellow);
                this.greetingSymbol.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Yellow);
                this.greetingSymbol.Symbol = Symbol.View;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.UpdateUIForNoFacesDetected();
        }

        TimeSpan latency = DateTime.Now - start;
        this.faceLantencyDebugText.Text = string.Format("Face API latency: {0}ms", (int)latency.TotalMilliseconds);

        this.isProcessingPhoto = false;
    }
```

In `GetSavedFilePhoto`, I passed the string names argument once the person is identified.

Code below for the `GetSavedFilePhoto` method

```
private void GetSavedFilePhoto(string personName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(personName)) return;

        var directoryPath = @"D:\PersonImages";

        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath);
        var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
```

However, in `GetSavedFilePhoto` method the variable `directories` returned an empty string of array when using `directoryPath` string variable.  Directory "D:\PersonImages" is a valid and existing folder in my machine and, it contains subfolders with images inside.  I also tried `Directory.GetFiles` to retrieve the jpg images but still returned an empty string.

I think it should work because I have used `Directory` class several times but not inside an `async`Task method. Does using `async` caused the files not returned when using I/O operation?

Sorry for this stupid question, but I really don't understand.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do your application has rights to read that files? Does it work not in async method?

Comment: @VMAtm It doesn't work in `async` method.  I think so, I'm debugging inside my Visual Studio and I found out that this method `Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath)` returned an empty string as well `Directory.GetFiles()`.  I have created a separate console application just to check if I did something wrong of using Directory class, but in the console app `GetDirectories` and `GetFiles` returned strings of array for the folders.  I think this is something related with the `async` Task operation.  Would you know any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: in UWP you cant randomly access folders like you do in var directoryPath = @"D:\PersonImages"; you need folder picker or use PictyreLibrary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/07wt70x2.aspx) or [`Directory.GetDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/c1sez4sc.aspx) method can get the folder/file in the local folder of the Application by the following code. But it could not open `D:\`.

```
var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path);
```

In UWP app you can only access two locations at default (local folder and install folder), others need capabilities setting or [file open picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker).Details please reference [file access permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

If you need access to all files in `D:\`, the user must manually pick the `D:\` drive using the `FolderPicker`, then you have permissions to access to files in this drive.

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation =
    Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Application now has read/write access to the picked file

        }
        else
        {
           //do some stuff
        }
```

Comment: Zhu, thank you for your answer.  I followed your UWP sample code and it worked.  I was now able to access D:\ and get the subfolders inside it.